# Is there a $1-1$ map of the interior of the $n$-simplex to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: geometry, simplex

I'm looking for a simple $1-1$ map from the interior of the standard $n$-simplex that covers $\mathbb{R}^n$. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you how to construct one.  Whether it is simple enough is for you to determine.  Position the simplex with the origin of $\Bbb R^n$ at its center.  Now scale every open radial segment in the simplex to $(0,\infty)$ by your favorite bijection.  In whatever direction you choose, let the distance from the origin to the simplex be $d$.  Take the point that is $r$ from the origin in the simplex and map it to the point that is$\frac 1{1-\frac rd}$ from the origin in $\Bbb R^n$.  The complicated part is coming up with $d$ given an angle of interest.

Comment: I was thinking of something similar, mapping the segment from the simplex centre to the boundary to a line from the origin to infinity in the same direction, then map to R^(n-1), perhaps by just taking the first n-1 coordinates. I was kind of hoping for something cleverer that doesn't require calculating a length for each point - lets see if anyone comes up with something ..